# Adapting RMP from using local realm

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using a local realm db and would like to add RMP on top of it. Is it possible to do that? e.g. User registers an account and then the realm is uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible to "convert" an unsynced Realm file to a synced Realm. You will have to open the unsynced Realm and a new synced Realm side-by-side, and copy the data over.

Comment: I've done that and it seems if I start to copy before the first sync is complete - the copied entry is no where to be found. Does that make sense?

Comment: No that's not expected - you should report an issue about that here: https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/new